# SBT docker:publish authentication issue

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am Using SBT Native Packager to build **Docker** Image,
and my *build.sbt* is :

```
   packageName in Docker := name.value
   version in Docker := version.value
   dockerBaseImage := "java"
   dockerRepository :=Some("index.docker.io/xyz")
   dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8283)
```

I am trying to publish image to private docker hub,but its giving

```
[error] unauthorized: authentication required.
```

in build.sbt how can i specify hub ***userName*** and ***Password***.

is there any other configuration that i am missing here.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#requirements), `It is currently not possible to provide authentication for Docker repositories from within the build.`

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Abanoub said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143146/sbt-dockerpublish-authentication-issue/39236983#comment65632312_39143146) this isn't possible via configuration. But you should be able to make the build work by executing `docker login` in your shell and the packager should then work as expected.